# Needs solution One drive partition have multiple part in my hardisk

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning

In my hard disk, one partition parted in multiple part. In my Computer Management setting, I saw drive D and Drive E is divided into multiple part.

[image: Multiple part of one drive]

When I use file explorer that is at one place. I can access them normally.

[image: Image of my drive in file explorer]

I need to make it normal. Just as C, D, E drive. One part for C, one for D, one for E.

[image: How I want]

***See Images to Understand my problem

Answer (score 0):

Look at the disk type: It says "Dynamic" for your cluttered one.

The only way (according to [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc755238(v=ws.11).aspx)) to convert the disk back to Basic is by backing up all data and then erasing all partitions. Then you can create new drive letters (partitions) and restore the data onto the disk.

Note that all Windows versions starting with 2000 support dynamic disks, so I see no reason why one needed to go through all those hoops in the first place.

Keep in mind that in your basic exaple you could not resize C: after D: was created. Dynamic disk format allows this until you run out of disk space.